# Client process executes server process

Tags: exec, posix

This is a homework Assignment.

"Bi-Directional Communication with Named Pipes in Unix"

The Assignment explicitly states: "Your client.c should be the only executable from the shell. The client MUST internally execute the server. Both, THE CLIENT and THE SERVER  MUST  Be Processes. ..."

This class has not mentioned how to interact with UNIX and the code in the operating systems book only provides C code implementation of main ideas for the topics covered.

There are many questions I have, but the first is: "How can a process start another process specifically to be independent from the initiating process in UNIX?"

For an example from class discussion: "The client should initiate the life of the server, but the server's life should be dependent. i.e. the client could die without killing the server, and multiple clients could interact with the server, but no matter how many clients are interacting- only a client can start the server and only one unique server should exist during a test."

Without having UNIX specific materials or referenced reading available I have "googled" to find fork() and exec() for the UNIX system.

Can a sequence of fork() and exec() calls sufficiently fulfill my requirement or is there a better way to manage this need?

Comment: your thinking is on the right track.

Comment: @user3629249: So if I ever want to execute another programs compiled code I should be using exec() and fork() to achieve this? Is this a best practice for the specific goal?

Comment: See http://meta.programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/6166/open-letter-to-students-with-homework-problems for some guidelines about asking better homework questions. In particular, it is probably not good to just ask for general direction. Instead, show what you have actually tried, what your understanding is, and explain where you get stuck or what you find confusing.

Comment: @seeksUnderstanding: this is an exercise to help understand processes (and the sequence of fork and exec calls that launch them).  This is the foundation on which the system is built; under the hood, every unix command is launched with fork and exec.  Best practices are usually higher level and language specific.  Working with fork/exec you will come to realize that it's really clever, but also really primitive.

Comment: @Andras: This assignment's objective "is to become familiar with the usage of Named Pipes for bi-directional communication on a single Unix System. The main idea is to investigate and successfully implement a peer-to-peer client-server modeled application, utilizing the Named Pipe Mechanism on the Unix based system, ..." Nothing in the program description or explanation of the requirements mentioned anything about POSIX, UNIX internal calls, or anything of the like. I'm making an assumption about exec(), and fork() but the class makes no mention/reference on how to interact with UNIX using C.

Comment: @Piet Delport: Thank you for the reference. I see now that I need to rewrite this question and give less garbage and more detail etc.

Comment: oh I see, this is just one step of several to follow.  Odd that the assignment is so specific then about having to fork the server from within the client.  Regular pipes are inherited, so there the fork is required, but named pipes can be used by any process, related or not.